# GridView TemplateField bound to SQL Statement?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu, templatefield

I have a Gridview with template fields conatining drop down lists. I need to populate the dropdownlists with a sql statement. My gridview code is as such:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ledger">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItemTempLedger" runat="server" Width="61px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="75px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the sql statement I need to populate it with is this:

```
SELECT V_VendorNo + '|' + V-VendorName FROM VendorTbl
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: have you tried sqldatasource? You can google that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not to get the dropdownlist in RowDataBound event of grid and assign datasource to it and bind it.

```
protected void GrdViewUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddlItemTempLedger = e.Row.FindControl("ddlItemTempLedger ") as DropDownList ;
        ddlItemTempLedger.DataSource = dt; //DataTable from database
        ddlItemTempLedger.DataTextField = "FieldForTextInDataTabledt";
        ddlItemTempLedger.DataValueField = "FieldForValueInDataTabledt";
        ddlItemTempLedger.DataBind();     
    }
}
```